# Convert an in query to join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Can i get some help to clean up following query and possibly convert it to joins.

```
SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.vacation_type_ids, pd.auto_vacation_theme
FROM property_details pd
WHERE pd.company_id =247
AND pd.status =  "active"
AND pd.id NOT 
IN (
    SELECT d.property_id
    FROM property_discount d
    WHERE (
    (
    d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
    AND d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
    AND d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE ) 
    AND d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
    )
    OR (
    d.start_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
    AND d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
    )
    OR (
    d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
    AND d.end_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
    )
)
)
```

I am not an expert with MySQL so sorry if i have did something wrong

Comment: As tombom explained, your WHERE clause is a mess.  How about this.  instead of what you DO NOT want, what is it you ARE trying to find in discounts to be excluded.  It appears, you want any job found that STARTED as a minimum of 4/15 and was completed on or before 4/17.  If so, these are the properties you want to "ignore" from the results.  Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole thing makes no sense to me.

```
WHERE (
(
d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
AND d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
AND d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE ) 
AND d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
)
OR (
d.start_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
AND d.start_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
)
OR (
d.end_date >= CAST(  "2012-04-15" AS DATE ) 
AND d.end_date <= CAST(  "2012-04-17" AS DATE )
)
)
```

The first block can get reduced to basically `start_date <= '2012-04-17' AND end_date >= '2012-04-17'`. This case gets handled by the second and third block which is basically `start_date BETWEEN '2012-04-15' AND '2012-04-17'` respectively `end_date BETWEEN '2012-04-15' AND '2012-04-17'`.

Do you really want an `OR` between this, or rather an `AND`?

You gave no information about your DB design, so I can only guess, if the following connection between these two tables is right.

```
SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.vacation_type_ids, pd.auto_vacation_theme
FROM property_details pd
INNER JOIN property_discount d ON pd.id = d.property_id
WHERE pd.company_id =247
AND pd.status =  'active'
(
d.start_date BETWEEN '2012-04-15' AND '2012-04-17' /*this is right when start_date is of type date, when it's datetime or timestamp you better write '2012-04-17 23:59:59', otherwise '2012-04-17 00:00:00' is assumed, which is basically not considering this date*/
OR
d.end_date BETWEEN '2012-04-15' AND '2012-04-17'
)
```